# How can I get values from a rangeslider for price calculation?

Tags: javascript, calculation, rangeslider

[Help me with a code that multiplies each value stored in a rangeslider by 10 and display the output in a specific place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6ZLF.png)

I'm in need of a code that multiplies each value assigned to a rangeslider by (any number) and display the output in a seperate place.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors  ++ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.